# .NET Core のアプリケーションから .NET Framework のアセンブリを参照する

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

.NET Core のアプリケーションから .NET Framework のアセンブリを参照し実行することは可能でしょうか。
DLLを直接指定して参照設定を追加し、コンパイルすることは出来ましたが、実行はできませんでした。

例）

- コンソールアプリケーション（.NET Core 2.2）を作成
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll を参照設定
- プラットフォームを `x86` に変更

Program.cs

```
var channel = new IpcServerChannel("SampleChannel");
```

デバッグ実行すると　エラーメッセージなどは表示されませんが、すぐにアプリケーションが終了します。

Answer (score 1):

詳細は理解しておらず、キーワードだけで探しましたが、こんなQ&Aがあります。

[.net core classlibrary calling .net framework class library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37608032/9014308)
2年前と古いのですが、解決した印があるので、参考になるかもしれません。以下は機械翻訳です。

> 通常の.NETライブラリとCoreプロジェクト間のコードを共有することは、共有プロジェクトを使用するだけでは機能しませんでした。なぜなら、Coreプロジェクトから参照できないためです。
>
> しかし、少しトリックで私はそれを動作させることができます。

同じQのもう一つの回答で紹介されていたのが、これです。
[Sharing code across platforms](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/04/21/sharing-code-across-platforms/)

他にはこんなQ&Aもあります。
[Calling a .Net Framework 4 (or Mono) assembly from a .Net Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42718943/9014308)

あと日本で何か関係があるかもしれないQ&Aがこれです。
[.NET Coreのコンソールアプリでdllを参照し，中身のクラスを利用すると例外が発生します](https://teratail.com/questions/96106)

何かの助けになれば。